# Why two definitions of localization of categories coincide?

Tags: ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, derived-categories

Let $\mathsf{C}$ be a category and $S$ be a collection of morphisms in $\mathsf{C}$. In this generality, we can construct the localization $S^{-1}\mathsf{C}$ by posing its objects to be the same as those in $\mathsf{C}$ and a morphism $M\to N$ to be a *path*

[image]

where the $L_i$ are objects of $\mathsf{C}$, the arrows to the right are morphisms of $\mathsf{C}$, and the arrows to the left are elements of $S$, up to equivalence. This equivalence relation, denoted $\sim$, says basically that compositions should behave well

[image]

that we may ignore identities

[image]

and that arrows to the left correspond to inverses

[image]

Usually, $S$ satisfies the axioms of a (left) multiplicative system which implies that every path is equivalent to a path of the form

[image]

which we call a *roof*. We wish to see if two roofs define the same morphism without ever dealing with longer paths, so we say that two roofs are $\sim_L$ equivalent if there exists an object $L$ in $\mathsf{C}$ and morphisms $p_1:L_1\to L$, $p_2:L_2\to L$ making the diagram

[image]

commute, and such that $p_2\circ s_2=p_1\circ s_1$ is in $S$.

In order for this to be useful, of course both notions should coincide. That is, there should exist a dashed isomorphism making the diagram

[image]

commute. I can verify that $\sim_L$ is indeed an equivalence relation (as is $\sim$), that such a map exists and that it is surjective. **How can I prove that it's also injective?**

Comment: The way I generally see this proved is by directly showing that the "Roof" description satisfies the universal property of the localisation, which implies it is equivalent to the other definition of the localisation rather than directly proving they are equivalent.

Comment: Dear @SimonHenry, I also know multiples references that do this. But I have to say that it feels very unsatisfying to me; basically the "raison d'être" of the axioms for a multiplicative system is the need to simplify paths, obtaining roofs. (This allows us to add morphisms when $\mathsf{C}$ is preadditive, for example.)

Comment: That is, it seems unsatisfying to me to ignore that we have a clear inclusion of the set of roofs in the set of paths.

Comment: I understand you want a more direct proof, and I don't know one in the literature. But you can directly translate the proofs I'm mentioning in what you are after, it is just going to be a little more complicated. It is important to note that the approach I'm mentioning do not "ìgnore" that roof are a special case of paths : the functor you get from the universal property send a roof to what the corresponding path is sent to. So you'll construct a functor from path to roof (up to equivalence) and show it is inverse to the obvious inclusions.

Comment: I guess a direct proof that it's injective should look like "if two roofs become equivalent, translate every use of one of the rules making paths equivalent to a use of one of the rules making roofs equivalent, using the fact that $S$ is a multiplicative system". This would be some sort of rewriting proof. It's tedious but it'll get you there

Comment: @MaximeRamzi the problem, I think, is that $\sim$-equivalence may take a roof to a path which is not a roof. That's what been bugging me

Comment: Yes, of course, it can, but you can replace that path by a roof in a way which is $\sim$-equivalent, but also so that the new roof is $\sim_L$-equivalent to the old one. The point is if you trace a $\sim$-path between two roofs, every path on the way there can be turned into a roof

Comment: I'm still a little confused, though. It's not clear to me at all how I could do this. I appreciate any further details. As you can see, this problem bothers me for a couple of months already...

Comment: I think the difficulty you speak of is precisely the reason why no one bothers with a direct proof. The equivalence relation on zigzags is just too messy.

Comment: @ZhenLin sure it's messy, but I don't understand why people don't seem to care. In basically every other context we are not satisfied to only know that two objects are isomorphic; we want to know if the isomorphism between them is what we expect. And in this case there's an obvious map! Moreover, I think this gives a very important "explanation" of the Ore / multiplicative system axioms: they're precisely what we need to turn paths into roofs!

Comment: Of course the isomorphism is the one you expect. In fact, it is unique. The localisation functor is an epimorphism.

Comment: Incidentally, the Gabriel–Zisman axioms are not the last word in what is needed to turn zigzags into (co)spans. They are sufficient but not necessary, as the case of a category of fibrant objects demonstrates.

Comment: I didn't know about this example; very interesting. On the other side, would you mind explaining why the localisation functor being epic implies that the isomorphism is the one I defined?

Comment: If $f$ is an epimorphism and $h$ is fixed, then there is at most one $g$ such that $h = g \circ f$. The localisation functor sends every morphism to "itself", and inverses are unique, so everything else is forced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a subtle viewpoint shift, which made everything way simpler. Instead of proving that our map is injective (which amounts to verifying that two $\sim$-equivalent roofs are $\sim_L$-equivalent, and is very messy), we define a left inverse. In case this may help someone in the future, I'll leave here my proof that this works.

(To be honest, this isn't as messy as I thought this would be. Verifying that the category whose morphisms are $\sim_L$-equivalence classes of roofs is indeed a category and satisfies the universal property of localisation in all details is actually worse.)

[image]

[image]

[image]